# Availability on usb stick?

Tags: boot, kubuntu

Is it possible to purchase kubuntu on a usb stick ready for installing? (64)

Many thanks.

Taffyjk

Comment: No. Only Ubuntu https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no place where you can buy a pre-made kubuntu live-USB. The closest thing is for regular Ubuntu. Check out what @Rinzwind said in the comment below the original question. [Canonical shop Ubuntu Live USB](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17)

> No. Only Ubuntu shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17 – Rinzwind

You can always burn your own USB drive from a Kubuntu ISO, though.